# roslibpy: why does TFClient seem to ignore the rate parameter?

Tags: ros, rosbridge, rosbridge-suite, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We're using `roslibpy` to capture `tf` messages from a robot via `rosbridge`, and rebroadcasting them on my local machine for viewing in `rviz`. So far, it works well, but I'd like to reduce bandwidth by lowering the message rate a little (we get them at about 10Hz). Setting the `rate` parameter in `TFClient` seems to have no effect. Here's the little `TFSub` class we're using:

```
class TFSub(object):
    """Manages a set of rosbridge callbacks associated with tfs
    on a remote robot."""
    def __init__(self, rosbridge_client):
        self.tf_client = TFClient(rosbridge_client, fixed_frame='map',
                                  angular_threshold=0.5,
                                  translation_threshold=0.5,
                                  rate=1.0)
        self.tf_client.subscribe('odom', self.tf_map_odom_cb)
        self.tf_client.subscribe('base_link', self.tf_map_base_link_cb)
        self.tb = tf.TransformBroadcaster()

    def tf_map_odom_cb(self, msg):
        rospy.logdebug("got a map->odom transform.")
        self.tb.sendTransform((msg['translation']['x'],
                               msg['translation']['y'],
                               msg['translation']['z']),
                              (msg['rotation']['x'],
                               msg['rotation']['y'],
                               msg['rotation']['z'],
                               msg['rotation']['w']),
                              rospy.Time.now(),
                              'odom',
                              'map')

    def tf_map_base_link_cb(self, msg):
        rospy.logdebug("got a map->base_link transform.")
        self.tb.sendTransform((msg['translation']['x'],
                               msg['translation']['y'],
                               msg['translation']['z']),
                              (msg['rotation']['x'],
                               msg['rotation']['y'],
                               msg['rotation']['z'],
                               msg['rotation']['w']),
                              rospy.Time.now(),
                              'base_link',
                              'map')
```

Here's our invocation of `tf2_web_republisher`, running on the remote robot:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find rosbridge_server)/launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch" />
  <node name="tf2_web_republisher_node" pkg="tf2_web_republisher" type="tf2_web_republisher" />
</launch>
```

As you can see, we're setting the `rate` parameter to 1.0, and setting a large `angular_threshold` and `translation_threshold`, but stll getting messages at just over 10.0Hz.

We're running Python 2.7 at both ends of the bridge, Ubuntu 14, ROS Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313844/roslibpy:-why-does-tfclient-seem-to-ignore-the-rate-parameter?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2019-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-27**:
[gramaziokohler/roslibpy#14](https://github.com/gramaziokohler/roslibpy/issues/14) seems related / similar.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2019-01-28**:
Thanks, I posted a link back here for the authors.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2019-01-28**:
@gvdhoorn: looks like a different issue from gramaziokohler/roslibpy#14. *That* one is about [subscriptions](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/blob/develop/ROSBRIDGE_PROTOCOL.md#344-subscribe), not `TFClient`. Thanks anyway.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-01-28**:
Which topic do you get at a rate of 10 Hz?
tf2_web_republisher seems to throttle properly,,

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2019-01-28**:
We're listening to two transforms: map->odom and map->base_link (code sample in the initial post). Setting the `rate` param to `TFClient` to a non-default value seems to make no difference.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-01-28**:
please check `rostopic hz /tf2_web_republisher/tf_repub_<X>` (replace `<X>` accordingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ugh, dumb mistake: I had a stray `static_transform_publisher` running. `TFClient` works exactly as documented.
Thanks to those who chimed in, and apologies for the distraction.

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2